# Changing focus (JTextArea and JOptionPane)

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextarea, joptionpane

In Swing, I am able to prompt the user for input using `JOptionPane`. The only problem this presents is the fact that the user can't change focus between the input box and the frame/content within it.

Is there any parameter I can put in to make it so that the focus is always on the frame. As a note, I have already tried `requestFocus()`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JOptionPane dialog is always modal. U can check this:

[Can I use a Java JOptionPane in a non-modal way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706455/can-i-use-a-java-joptionpane-in-a-non-modal-way)

in order to bypass this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of JOptionPane is to show a *modal* dialog, which asks for confirmation or option, and to continue once the user has chosen an option. Without the chosen option, the program can't continue.

If you would like a non-modal dialog, then you'll need to construct it yourself, using JDialog.