# How to infinitely run a keylistener until it registers certain input?

Tags: java, loops, window, keylistener

Currently, I'm trying to have a very basic tool enable the user to move objects around while seeing them update on the screen, but only at a specific time (when they have the object to move selected). So I initially thought I could just have a JOptionPane message up, and have the user move the object around until they were happy with it, and then press ok in the box to stop their motion and finalize the position.

Like this:

```
inMotion=true;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    frame,
    "Move object to spot using arrow keys",
    "Edit Object",
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
inMotion=false;
```

With KeyPressed Code like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    int moveX=0;
    int moveY=0;
    if(inMotion)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){moveY=-1;}
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){moveX=-1;}
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){moveX=1;}
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){moveY=1;}
        //Set object position code here
    }
}
```

The separate window, however, apparently doesn't allow the keylistener to run for the main frame. So following this up I tried a while loop, to just hold the user once they closed the pane until they pressed enter, which would set the position.

Like this:

```
inMotion=true;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    frame,
    "Move object to spot using arrow keys",
    "Edit Object",
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
while(inMotion){}
```

Where KeyPressed had this line added in the loop

```
if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){inMotion=false;}
```

However, the infinite loop won't allow the keylistener to run either, even though the user is focused on the right window. I tried using commands

```
frame.setEnabled(true); 
And
frame.enableInputMethods(true);
```

but this doesn't work either, and I really don't know what they do anyway, so that's probably not good. Any help getting the keylistener to check the keys at the right time would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you are displaying the OptionPane while waiting for the input? I don't think you can do that, the JOptionPane is for modal dialogs only. You'd be best off to display your message in [a dialog class of your own.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706455/can-i-use-a-java-joptionpane-in-a-non-modal-way)

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple threads, a non-modal state for the overlaying window, and even adding a keylistener to the external window. Eventually, I found that I could just do a work around by having the main window itself just freeze commands through a boolean, which would be set true at the end of the inputs.

```
//inputs
//gets width,height,etc of item
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Move the item using arrow keys"
+" and press enter when it is in the correct place.");
inMotion=true;

//draw method
if(!inMotion)
{Every other command in the tool}
else
{just draw motion of the object}
```

and then  the keylistener would have the enter key disable inmotion